# Difference In $\vec{i}$ , $\vec{j}$, $\vec{k}$ vector and $\hat{i}$ , $\hat{j}$, $\hat{k}$ cap?

Tags: vectors, definition, notation

There are actually two ways in which unit vector is shown in my textbook.

The first one is: $\hat i, \hat j, \hat k $.

The second one is: $\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k}$.

What is the difference between these two ways they are written?

[image]

Comment: Need more context for that. Usually for a vector $\vec{v}$ one denotes as $\hat{v}$ the unit vector $\frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}$. I don't know if that's the case in your book.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I have a attached a photo from book.

Comment: The photo only shows $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$, not $\hat{\imath}$, $\hat{\jmath}$.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that this book is some cheap knock-off textbook with poor editing?

Comment: @JEB This book is not some cheap book.It is a great book in fact

Comment: Presumably the book is using $\vec i$ and $\vec j$ as unit vectors along the $x$ and $y$ axes. There are many different conventions for vector notation (and personally I prefer just bold face letters to covering page after page with little arrows).

Comment: It is one and the same thing right

Comment: Yes $\vec{i}$ and $\hat{i}$ are the same thing here.It is a very common confusion in  some textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that $\hat{i}$ denotes the direction of vector $\vec{i}$ while $\vec{i}$ denotes the whole vector.

---

In general, every vector $\vec{a}$ has two parts: its magnitude $|\vec{a}|$ and its direction $\hat{a}$. It is just the conventional notation.
$$\vec{a}=|\vec{a}|\hat{a}$$

**EDIT**

However, it is just the notation; your book prefers the notation $\vec{i}$ for writing the unit vectors, which isn't much issue as long as you clarify the nomenclature before using the vectors.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is it that i vector is like unit magnitude + direction whereas i cap is just direction.

Comment: Yes, exactly! It is not special for $i$, $j$ and $k$; it can be used for any vector.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 With the photo the OP added (v2) seems like their textbook is not using this convention

Comment: That does not seem compatible with convention or the photo shown.  What would the magnitude of coordinate-oriented vectors be?

Comment: @Brick: My answer was written before that image was added. I didn't know that; I'm editing my answer accordingly!

Comment: Yes @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə, I made my amends.